# How to display one or multiple images based on the content of a field from a pass through file

Tags: javascript

I am currently designing a label template using Loftware Label Manager. Using Javascript, How do I  Display one or multiple images based on the content of a field in my passthrough file(.csv). The field can contain these values or parts of them:

“bomb, corrosive, exclamation, environment, flame, flameO, gas, health, skull", some fields contain "exclamation" or some "corrosive, environment," etc.

Each value should represent an image (e.g. corrosive.png or environment.png)

I have no idea how to create this so the proper image or images appear on the label, depending on the value of the field in the passthrough file.

I currently have this script, but it only displays a single image. Any ideas?

```
var input =(label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto').@data);

if(input == "exclamation")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image6').@data="exclamation.png";

}

else if(input == "health")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image2').@data="health.png";

}

else if(input == "environment")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image3').@data="environment.png";

}

else if(input == "corrosion")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image5').@data="corrosion.png";

}

else if(input == "flame")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image7').@data="flame.png";

}

else if(input == "skull")

{

label.fields.field.(@name == 'picto_image8').@data="skull.png";

}
```